# php plugin based script

Tags: php, plugins

I'm thinking of building a plugin based application.
At the moment, I am not sure what type of plugins will be used so I don't have a requirement.

I wish to know how such applications are designed so I can start my application around that.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I don't mind what sort of system it is or what your plugins do. What I want are some ideas on how others have achieved this so I can formulate and make my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for all of my plugins: http://failover.co.za/2010/10/20/writing-a-pluggable-php-application-part-1/

If the plugins are going to be built by people who won't be editing the script, then you can just include the file for the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better for you to work with MVC Framework and then create an application core (modules and all apps need and require this), then think global and create other apps and modules.

Also I suggest you look at an Open Source CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a framework for this. I need an application built from scratch. I wanted to look at wordpress, but that seems too high level for my needs

Comment: http://www.henriquebarroso.com/how-to-create-a-simple-mvc-framework-in-php/ &  http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/